# How can I install GnuTLS in MinGW/MSYS?

Tags: packages, mingw, msys

I've installed MinGW and MSYS on my Windows XP machine and now I want to compile an application which requires the GnuTLS libraries.

**How do I install that package?**

I tried **mingw-get install mingw-gnutls** without success.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `mingw-gnutls` package.

```
mingw-get list | grep -i gnutls
```

So you would have to install it from source.

## [ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnutls](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnutls)